# Maven Multi-Modules Clean and Build Failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am getting following warnings while cleaning and building my project

```
     Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
     com.salesforce:Main:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.
exclusions.exclusion.artifactId'
     for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id 
    pattern. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.0.RELEASE, 
    C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
    dependencies\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.0.RELEASE.pom, line 
    2753, column 25
```

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

My Parent Pom.xml is following : -

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>Models</module>
    <module>Utilities</module>
    <module>Services</module>
    <module>WebControllers</module>
    <module>Main</module>
</modules>

<groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
<artifactId>rstkapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rstkm-api</name>
<description>Salesforce REST API</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>Models</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>WebControllers</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>Main</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dependencies for Apache Kafka-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.54</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>42.2.9.jre7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1.SP2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>
```

My Main Module pom.xml is following : -

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<artifactId>Main</artifactId>
<groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <artifactId>rstkapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Models</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>WebControllers</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and My WebController Module pom.xml is following : -

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<artifactId>WebControllers</artifactId>
<groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <artifactId>rstkapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Models</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.salesforce</groupId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have some more pom.xml files for other modules, If it would be required, i will share those files as well.

Sometime when i build project with dependencies it works, and sometime, it doesn't, I am unable to figure out the reason, why is it working sometime, if project has bugs?

Comment: I believe running only the `clean` doesn't output in errors, could you confirm?

Comment: Yes, you are right, clean is success

Comment: Are you using a really old version of Maven? If yes, then try using a newer version. (It looks like wildcard excludes were added in [Maven 3.2.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) so you are probably using a version older than that).

Comment: In addition to @Jasper comment, give us the output of `mvn -version` command

Comment: after running mvn -version command on cli, i got this version apache-maven-3.6.1

Comment: Can you please make a working example on GitHub to take a look?...

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like you are using Maven version less than https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html where this has been introduced ...

Comment: Apart from the thing that you are manually defining several dependencies with your own version which I strongly discourage based on the idea of Spring Boot projects which already have large number of defined versions....

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry, its in private repository, not allowed to share.
i am using maven version 3.6.1
yes i knew about spring boot parent and its auto picking version. i will use it.
by the way, it's work fine on intelliJ but give error on netbeans. it's all random behaviour, sometime work on both IDEs sometime not on both, sometime work on 1 not on other.

Comment: What do you mean by: It's working on IDEA IntelliJ but give errors in Netbeans so you are building in your IDE and not on plain command line? Which versions of Netbeans/IDEA IntelliJ?

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 and IntelliJ 11.0.4,
In command line mvn clean install and mvn clean package give error every time although mvn dependency:tree give success

Comment: Extreme old versions of Netbeans as well of IntelliJ ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204599/discussion-between-muhammad-waqar-and-khmarbaise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of maven version

1. which you can figure out by command mvn --version

[image: maven version]

2. which is in pom.xml in plugin section

[image: maven compile dependency version]

So by adding following code in my parent pom.xml : -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Previously i was using maven version 3.1.1, by updating maven version in pom.xml from 3.1.1 to 3.8.1, it fixed the issue.